# How to extract a collection of numbers from a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I need to extract a project number out of a string. If the project number was fixed it would have been easy, however it can be either `P.XXXXX`, `P XXXXX` or `PXXXXX`.

Is there a simple function like `preg_match` that I could use? If so, what would my regular expression be?

Comment: Is the `XXXXX`  always 5 digit length?

Comment: Either 4 or 5 digit length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed - if this is part of a larger string e.g. `"The project (P.12345) is nearly done"`, you can use:

```
preg_match('/P[. ]?(\d{5})/',$str,$match);
$pnumber = $match[1];
```

Otherwise, if the string will always just be the `P.12345` string, you can use:

```
preg_match('/\d{5}$/',$str,$match);
$pnumber = $match[0];
```

Though you may prefer the more explicit match of the top example.

Comment: It is part of a larger string. And this works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: @DarkRanger No worries, glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('#P[. ]?(\d{5})#', $project_number, $matches) {
    $project_version = $matches[1];
}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UWjIArlS3Lq5hCD_)

Comment: Thanks for the graphic. It does make me understand what is said in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You said that project number is 4 of 5 digit length, so:

```
preg_match('/P[. ]?(\d{4,5})/', $tring, $m);
$project_number = $m[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `explode()` function to split those

Comment: With which delimiter?

Comment: @M42 using the project number

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: Thought he has the project number as input. By the way for this how the preg_match should work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract the XXXXX from the string and XXXXX are all integers, you can use the following.

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
```

You can use the `^` or *caret* character inside square brackets to negate the expression. So in this instance it will replace anything that isn't a number with nothing.

Comment: The thing is, that's not the only numbers in the string.

Comment: The string would be something like: `COMPANY_TECH INFO_REPORT_RXXX_P.XXXXX Some title of document Ed 4 2006.pdf`. `P.XXXX` could be either `P.XXXXX` or `P XXXXX` or `PXXXXX`. My accepted answer solves my issue. Thanks for the assistance though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this kind of regex : `/.*P[ .]?(\d+).*/`

Here is a few test lines :

```
$string = 'This is the P123 project, with another useless number 456.';
$project = preg_replace('/.*P[ .]?(\d+).*/', '$1', $string); 
var_dump($project);

$string = 'This is the P.123 project, with another useless number 456.';
$project = preg_replace('/.*P[ .]?(\d+).*/', '$1', $string);
var_dump($project);

$string = 'This is the P 123 project, with another useless number 456.';
$project = preg_replace('/.*P[ .]?(\d+).*/', '$1', $string);
var_dump($project);
```

Comment: The `.*`  are not usefull here.